# Close window from within a view in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, javascript-security

I'm trying to close a window from within a view in AnglarJS but I'm getting this error:

> Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

This is the script in `index.html`:

```
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
    app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {templateUrl: 'main.html', controller: 'mainCtrl'})
            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    });
    app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, $window) {
        $scope.$route = $route;
        $scope.$location = $location;
        $scope.$routeParams = $routeParams;
        $scope.closeApp = function(){
                $window.close();
        };
    });
```

and this is `main.html`:

```
<button ng-click="closeApp()">Close this app please</button>
```

I'm aware that [from the latest working spec for window.close()](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/browsers.html#dom-window-close):

> The close() method on Window objects should, if all the following conditions are met, close the browsing context A:
>
> - The corresponding browsing context A is script-closable.
> - The browsing context of the incumbent script is familiar with the browsing context A.
> - The browsing context of the incumbent script is allowed to navigate the browsing context A.

But how come that I'm getting this? Am I not within the same context?! And how to fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: Did your angularJS app open the window in the first place?

Comment: No. The angularJS app is within the index.html.

Comment: If we look at the message shown by the app "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it" and you just told me that your app didn't open the window ... doesn't this imply you can't script close the window since your app didn't open it in the first place.

Comment: Yep! I've arrived to that conclusion too 5 minutes ago and I'm feeling a little bit stupid.. :-P All I have to do is to open a new window then close it.. Too bad `open(location, '_self').close();` doesn't work no more.. Thank you anyway! :-)